# I need bit manipulation guide / reference material for c#

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Most common C# bitwise operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93744/most-common-c-bitwise-operations)

I am looking for bit manipulation reference material for c#.
And, OR, XOR, left shift , right shift.
setting a bit
All operations with bit.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93744/most-common-c-bitwise-operations/317065#317065

Answer (score 1):

[This was just posted today and should be helpful.](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/low-level-bit-hacks-you-absolutely-must-know/)  It covers a variety of bit operations, and the operations should be translatable directly to C#.

Answer (score 0):

These are all the standard C-style operators.

http://www.space.unibe.ch/comp_doc/c_manual/C/CONCEPT/bitwise.html

I am not sure if C# has 1's complement.

**Edit** it does.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d%28VS.71%29.aspx