# Byte formatting

Tags: c#, byte

Hello I'am new to using bytes in C#.

Say if I want to compare bytes based on the forms 0xxxxxxx and 1xxxxxxx. How would I get that first value for my comparison and at the same time remove it from the front?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: What do you mean by "remove it from the front"? The front of what? Please clarify your question.

Comment: I dont understand a thing

Comment: You want to compare *bits*?

Comment: yeah that's the term i'm looking for. I want to compare bits. Sorry I'm completely new to using bytes and bits.

Comment: Still, how/where are those bits stored?

Comment: First hit on google: _comparing bits c#_  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1929343/bitwise-and-on-32-bit-integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand, but in C#, to write the binaray number 1000'0000, you must use hex notation. So to check if the left-most (most significant) bits of two bytes match, you can do e.g.

```
byte a = ...;
byte b = ...;

if ((a & 0x80) == (b & 0x80))
{
  // match
}
else
{
  // opposite
}
```

This uses bit-wise AND. To clear the most significant bit, you may use:

```
byte aModified = (byte)(a & 0x7f);
```

or if you want to assign back to `a` again:

```
a &= 0x7f;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use binary operations like

```
a&10000
a<<1
```

Answer (score 0):

This will check two bytes and compare each bit. If the bit is the same, it will clear that bit.

```
     static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        byte byte1 = 255;
        byte byte2 = 255;

        for (var i = 0; i <= 7; i++)
        {
            if ((byte1 & (1 << i)) == (byte2 & (1 << i)))
            {
                // position i in byte1 is the same as position i in byte2

                // clear bit that is the same in both numbers
                ClearBit(ref byte1, i);
                ClearBit(ref byte2, i);
            }
            else
            {
                // if not the same.. do something here
            }

            Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(byte1, 2).PadLeft(8, '0'));
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void ClearBit(ref byte value, int position)
    {
        value = (byte)(value & ~(1 << position));
    }
}
```