# Working with File Attributes in C# .Net 2.0

Tags: c#, file-attributes, directory-walk

So how can i recursively search a Folder and un-hide ALL files and sub folders in a directory? Like have it check each file and each folder... if they're hidden.. un-hide them. Iv been messing around with it all morning with no luck... i got all folders to set back to normal but thats about it.

Comment: provide the code you are currently using plz ..

Comment: Un/hide the directory, not the files.

Answer (score 4):

```
foreach (var filePath in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Temp2"))
{
    Console.Write("File " + filePath);

    FileAttributes fileAttribute = File.GetAttributes(filePath);

    if ((fileAttribute & FileAttributes.Hidden) > 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" is hidden.");

        // unset the hidden flag, but do not change other flags:
        File.SetAttributes(filePath, fileAttribute & ~FileAttributes.Hidden);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" is not hidden.");
    }
}
```

to do it recursively, use

```
Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Temp2", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

to include directories too, use [`GetFileSystemEntries`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getfilesystementries.aspx)

```
Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(@"C:\Temp2", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
foreach (var file in directory.GetFiles())
{
    if ((File.GetAttributes(file.FullName) & FileAttributes.Hidden) == FileAttributes.Hidden)
    {
         File.SetAttributes(file.FullName, FileAttributes.Normal);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easily solved using recursion.

File attributes such as "hidden" is specified as an enum flag and is most easliy set or cleared using [bit operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93744/most-common-c-bitwise-operations). You can see a file or directory's attributes by getting a [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) or [DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx) for that path.

```
// startDir assumed to be full path
public static void UnhideAll(string startDir)
{
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(startDir);
    Console.WriteLine("Working in {0}", startDir);
    // First, clear hidden flag on the current directory (if needed)
    if ((dir.Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) != 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Clearing hidden flag on dir");
        dir.Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.Hidden;
    }
    else
        Console.WriteLine("No need to clear flag since it's already non-hidden");

    // Second, recursively go into all sub directories
    foreach (var subDir in dir.GetDirectories())
        UnhideAll(subDir.FullName);

    // Third, fix all hidden files in the current folder
    foreach (var file in dir.GetFiles())
    {
        if ((file.Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) != 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Clearing hidden flag on file {0}", file.FullName);
            file.Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.Hidden;
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Skipping {0} since it's not hidden", file.FullName);
    }
}
```

You can now recursively unhide all hidden files inside a directory by calling

```
UnhideAll(@"C:\SomePath\That\Should\Be\Unhidden");
```

Of course, you'll want to remove all calls to `Console.WriteLine` when you use this code but I left them there to make it easier for you to see what's going on when the code is running. Here's a more condense version:

```
// startDir assumed to be full path
public static void UnhideAll(string startDir)
{
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(startDir);
    // First, clear the current directory
    dir.Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.Hidden;
    // Second, recursively go into all sub directories
    foreach (var subDir in dir.GetDirectories())
        UnhideAll(subDir.FullName);

    // Third, fix all hidden files in this folder
    foreach (var file in dir.GetFiles())
        file.Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.Hidden;
}
```