# What does "~" mean before enums

Tags: c#, syntax, enums

Today I see this code:

```
ViewBag.country = from p in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures & ~CultureTypes.NeutralCultures)
                              select new SelectListItem
                              {
                                  Text = p.EnglishName,
                                  Value = p.DisplayName
                              };
```

And I can not understand. "~" - This is a mistake? As far as I remember, "~" is placed before the destructors. But this is enum. And this code compiled!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/93744/284240

Comment: `~` isn't the only symbol with multiple unrelated meanings. There's `*`: pointers and multiplication have little to do with each other.

Comment: @CuongLe no it isn't; at the individual bit level, 0 &~ 1 => 0, where- as 0 ^ 1 => 1. Or to take a concrete example: 3 &~ 5 => 2, 3 ^ 5 => 6. In this example 3 and 5 are binary `0011` and `0101`, deliberately chosen to create a truth-table. If `&~` was "equal with" `^`, the result would be identical.

Comment: @MarcGravell: you are right

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's bitwise negation operator.

[~ Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2bd4x66.aspx)

> The `~` operator performs a bitwise complement operation on its operand,
>   which has the effect of reversing each bit. Bitwise complement
>   operators are predefined for `int`, `uint`, `long`, and `ulong`.

And because *operations on integral types are generally allowed on enumeration* you can use `~` with enums backed with types listed above.

Comment: Useful for enumerations that are marked with `FlagsAttribute` (as are the other bitwise operators).