# Designing a Windows Azure Tables database for storing checkboxes states

Tags: azure, database-design, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, nosql

With zero experience designing non-relational databases (Azure Storage Tables, to be specific), I'm having trouble coming up with a good design to store the data for my application.

The application is really simple. It is basically a multi-user To-Do list:

```
User selects a "Procedure".
User gets presented with webpage with several checkboxes.
User starts checking checkboxes.
Each check/uncheck gets stored in the DB.
```

For example, let's say that we have a procedure to obtain Milk:

```
Procedure 1 - How to obtain Milk:
    [_] Step 1 - Open fridge
    [_] Step 2 - Get Milk
    [_] Step 3 - Close fridge
```

Alice decides to execute this procedure, so she creates a new execution and starts checking checkboxes:

```
Procedure 1, Execution 1:
    Executor(s): Alice
    [X] Step 1 - Open fridge
    [X] Step 2 - Get Milk
    [_] Step 3 - Close fridge
```

Bob, also decides to execute this procedure, but not together with Alice. So, Bob creates a new execution. Charlie, on the other hand wants to help Bob, so instead of creating a new execution he joins Bob's execution:

```
Procedure 1, Execution 2:
    Executor(s): Bob, Charlie
    [_] Step 1 - Open fridge
    [X] Step 2 - Get Milk
    [_] Step 3 - Close fridge
```

In summary, we can have multiple procedures, and each procedure can have multiple executions:

[image: Procedure Execution relationship]

So, we need a way to store procedures (a list of checkboxes); executions (who, when, checkboxes states); and the history of checks/unchecks.

**This is what I have come up with so far:**

- Create three tables: *Procedures*, *Executions*, *Actions*.
- The *Procedures* table stores what checkboxes are there in each procedure.
- The *Executions* table stores who and when initiated the execution of a Procedure, and the checkboxes states.
- The *Actions* table stores every checkbox check and uncheck, including who and when.

I'm not too happy with this approach for a number of reasons. For instance, every time a user clicks on a checkbox we need to update the Executions table row and insert a new row into the Actions table at the same time. Also, I'm not sure if this design will scale for a really large number of Procedures, Executions, and Actions.

What would be a good way to store this data using Azure Storage Tables, or a similar NoSQL store? How would you go about designing this database? And, how would you partition the data (row keys, partition keys)?

Comment: Note that NoSQL is a very broad term. Every NoSQL database works differently. What would work well for MongoDB wouldn't work for Azure Tables or Neo4j.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Philipp. I understand that every NoSQL database works differently. However, they also have many things in common. My understanding is that some design practices can be shared across *similar* non-relational stores. But, I could be wrong.

Comment: The design of the storage tables and keys depends on requirements and usage patterns. Do you need to store the history of all changes or only the latest state? Do you need to run reports on the current state and or historical state? Do you expect a predominance of reads or writes in the application over time? By what criteria will you need to select records and report? How many records do you expect to store (hundreds/thousands/millions)? Is this a multitenant application requiring partitioning of records by tenant? and so on...

Comment: That is a good list of considerations Nathan. This is the kind of insight I'm after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't need to coerce Azure tables into a relational structure. They're very fast and very cheap, and designed so you can dump blocks of data in and worry about the structure when you retrieve it.

Second, correctly identifying and structuring your partition keys makes retrieval even faster.

Third, Azure tables don't have to have uniform structures. You can store different kinds of data within one table, even with the same partition keys. This opens up possibilities not available to an RDBMS.

So how are you planning to retrieve the data? What are the use cases?

Let's say your primary use case is to retrieve the data by time, like an audit log. In that case, I would suggest this approach:

- Put your procedures, executions, and actions all within the same table.
- Create a new table for each unit of time that gives you tens of thousands to hundreds of thousands of rows per table, or some other unit that makes sense. (For one project I've done recently, the application's event log uses one table per month, with each table growing to around 100,000 rows.)
- Create a partition key that gives you hundreds to thousands of rows per partition. (We use hours remaining until `DateTimeOffset.MaxValue`. When you query an Azure table without using a partition key, you see the lowest partitions first. This descending-hourly scheme means the most recent hour's entries are at the top of the results pane in our Azure tool.)
- Structure your row keys to be human-readable. Remember they need to be unique within the table. So possibly a row key like `Procedure_Bob_ID12345_20140514-134630Z_unique` where unique is a counter or hash would work.
- When you query for data, pull back the entire partition--remember, it's just a few hundred rows--and filter the results in memory, where it's faster.

Say you have a second use case where you need to retrieve data by user name. Simple: within the *same table*, add a second row containing the same data but with a partition key based on the user name (`bob_execution_20140514`).

Another thing to consider is storing the entire procedure *etc.* object graphs in the table. Getting back to our logging example, a log entry might have detailed information, so we just plop an entire block of JSON right in the table. (We're usually retrieving it in an Azure cloud service, so the network throughput isn't a meaningful constraint as Azure-to-Azure speeds within the same region are gigabits per second.)

Comment: Can you give a little bit of insight in how would you handle updating the data? I know in your case is audit log info, so no need to update. But in my example, would you just insert a new row for each modification, or update the existing row?

Comment: You could do either. Again, it depends on the retrieval use cases. But there's no problem updating a row--you just need the partition and row keys. If you want to update rows without reading them in first, you'll need deterministic row keys, which can get a little tricky. However, you get a full 1 KB for your row key if you want, so it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on usage approach use either Procedure ID or a combination of ProcedureID-ExecutionID.  Don't worry about building a quasi-relational model - just choose the right partition key based on how you are most likely to create or consume the data in the majority of cases (i.e. will you care more about procedures, executions, assignees or steps in the longer term and how might you retrieve all items related to a single entity such a procedure in a single query?)

Depending on volume of steps in a procedure you might not even care too much about how step values are tracked (maybe using an integer or enum that could be combined via a bitwise operator?) see - [Most common C# bitwise operations on enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93744/most-common-c-sharp-bitwise-operations-on-enums)

Comment: Simon, what do you mean by a quasi-relational model? Do you mean I drop the idea of multiple tables and go with a single big table? If so, what is the benefit in that?

Comment: Table storage is a flat structure and any data normalisation doesn't really apply to it.  If you choose the right partition key you shouldn't need multiple tables. See here for useful intro to Tablve storage vs a more traditional relational model: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff796231.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The selection of PK, RK and other table properties depends on how you are going to use the data, your dominant query and application behavior.  The storage team blob (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/11/06/how-to-get-most-out-of-windows-azure-tables.aspx) has guidance on this for common scenarios.

Comment: As Samarth says, the important consideration is how you will use the data.  With table storage, you don't want any particular partition to be "too big" or "too small".  Find the sweet spot with your use cases that produces at most a few thousand records per partition.  That's likely to be right.  Give more details on your use cases if you want better guidance.  Also - with Azure table storage, storing data twice or more times with different keys can be a valuable technique.  Even multiple tables with the same data works well.  Table storage is fast!  (use JSON data types!)