# How to build a many-to-many relation between a model and an enum, in EF code first?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm, ef-code-first, code-first

For example:

```
public class Role
{
    public Role()
    {
        Permissions = new HashSet<Permission>();
    }

    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }
}

public enum Permission
{
    UserManagement = 0,
    DepartmentManagement = 1,
    RoleManagement = 2,
    ModifyPassword = 3
}
```

Normally, between a model and another model, I can write two navigation properties. But for this situation, I cannot write a navigation property in an enum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you do something like this instead?

```
[Flags]
public enum Permission
{
    UserManagement = 1,
    DepartmentManagement = 2,
    RoleManagement = 4,
    ModifyPassword = 8
}

public class Role
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Permission Permissions { get; set; }
}
```

And then, for example:

```
var role = new Role();
//assign multiple values
role.Permissions = Permission.UserManagement | Permission.ModifyPassword;
//add a value
role.Permissions |= Permission.DepartmentManagement;
//remove a value
role.Permissions &= ~Permission.DepartmentManagement;
//test for a value
bool hasPermission = (role.Permissions & Permission.ModifyPassword) != 0;
```

**Warning:**

Possibly consider exposing a few methods like `RemovePermission(...)`, `AddPermission(...)`, etc to make it harder to introduce a pretty significant bug if someone mishandles a bitwise operations.

Unless it's a performance requirement or something, I'd probably just make permissions a class and live with the overhead.

**Some reading:**

- [Designing Flag Enums](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229062(v=vs.100).aspx)
- [Enum.HasFlag()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [FlagAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Most common C# bitwise operations on enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93744/most-common-c-sharp-bitwise-operations-on-enums)