# How can I reduce this method without using the If condition?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, filter

I'm trying to use the entity framework to filter my GET method... Using the if the condition it's working

```
 public async Task<List<TimeEntryViewModel>> Get(TimeEntryFilter filter)
        {
            var result = await _readRepository
                .FindByCondition(x => x.IsApproved == true)
                .Include(x => x.Task)
                .Include(x => x.Account)
                .Select(x => new TimeEntryViewModel
                {
                    AccountName = x.Account.Name,
                    Date = x.Date,
                    StartTime = x.StartTime,
                    FinishTime = x.FinishTime,
                    InternalId = x.InternalId,
                    TaskId = x.TaskId,
                    TaskName = x.Task.Name,
                    CreatedBy = x.CreatedBy,
                    CustomerName = x.Task.Project.ServiceOrder.Customer.Name
                }).ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

            if  (filter.AccountName != null || 
                (filter.StartDate.HasValue && filter.FinishDate.HasValue && (filter.StartDate <= filter.FinishDate)) ||
                (filter.TaskName != null) ||
                (filter.CustomerName != null) ||
                (filter.InternalId != null))
                result = result.Where(x => 
                                        (x.AccountName.ToString().Contains(filter.AccountName)) &&
                                        (x.Date >= filter.StartDate && x.Date <= filter.FinishDate) &&
                                        (x.CustomerName.ToString().Contains(filter.CustomerName)) &&
                                        (x.TaskName.ToString().Contains(filter.TaskName)) &&
                                        (x.InternalId.ToString().Contains(filter.InternalId.ToString()))).ToList();

            return result;
        }
```

But I imagine that there is a way to improve this method without using if

I'd had already tried to do that (Just filter account name to show)
But returned Internal Server Error

```
var result = await _readRepository
                .FindByCondition(x => x.IsApproved == true)
                .Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.AccountName) || x.Account.Name.ToString().Contains(filter.AccountName))
                .Include(x => x.Task)
                .Include(x => x.Account)
                .Select(x => new TimeEntryViewModel
                {
                    Id = x.Id,
                    AccountName = x.Account.Name,
                    Date = x.Date,
                    Description = x.Description,
                    StartTime = x.StartTime,
                    FinishTime = x.FinishTime,
                    InternalId = x.InternalId,
                    OnSite = x.OnSite,
                    IsApproved = x.IsApproved,
                    IsBillable = x.IsBillable,
                    TaskId = x.TaskId,
                    TaskName = x.Task.Name,
                    CreatedBy = x.CreatedBy,
                    CustomerName = x.Task.Project.ServiceOrder.Customer.Name
                }).ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Okay Guys EDIT1: In my second sample, using InternalId instead of Account.Name

```
.Where(x => (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.InternalId.ToString())) || x.InternalId.ToString().Contains(filter.InternalId.ToString()))
```

it worked.... I believe that I'm having trouble to work with something that is a foreign key in my table...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, apparently, my problem was `.Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.AccountName) || x.Account.Name.ToString().Contains(filter.AccountName))` after x.Account.Name I can't use ToString()... I don't know exactly why, but now works without the if condition

```
public async Task<List<TimeEntryViewModel>> GetApproved(TimeEntryFilter filter)
        {
            var result = await _readRepository
                .FindByCondition(x => x.IsApproved == true)
                .Include(x => x.Task)
                .Include(x => x.Account)
                .Where(x => 
                            (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.InternalId.ToString()) || x.InternalId.ToString().Contains(filter.InternalId.ToString())) &&
                            (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.AccountName) || x.Account.Name.Contains(filter.AccountName)) && 
                            (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.CustomerName) || x.Task.Project.ServiceOrder.Customer.Name.Contains(filter.CustomerName)) &&
                            (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.TaskName) || x.Task.Name.Contains(filter.TaskName)))
                .Select(x => new TimeEntryViewModel
                {
                    Id = x.Id,
                    AccountName = x.Account.Name,
                    Date = x.Date,
                    Description = x.Description,
                    StartTime = x.StartTime,
                    FinishTime = x.FinishTime,
                    InternalId = x.InternalId,
                    OnSite = x.OnSite,
                    IsApproved = x.IsApproved,
                    IsBillable = x.IsBillable,
                    TaskId = x.TaskId,
                    TaskName = x.Task.Name,
                    CreatedBy = x.CreatedBy,
                    CustomerName = x.Task.Project.ServiceOrder.Customer.Name
                }).ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

            return result;
        }
```

If anyone knows why it's working, I'll be thankful

Answer (score 1):

There is a very interesting way to mass multiple bool values (contains or not etc) with only one value. It's called bit bitwise operations. Here: [Most common C# bitwise operations on enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93744/most-common-c-sharp-bitwise-operations-on-enums)
you can find different approachs to this "technique".

Answer (score 1):

It returned null because you don't check if `Account` property is null.

```
 AccountName = x.Account.Name
```

So the above will throw a Null Reference Exception.

A way to avoid this, it is to use the [null conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-):

```
AccountName = x.Account?.Name
```

You can follow the same approach also for properties like:

- `Task.Name`
- `Task.Project.ServiceOrder.Customer.Name`

And access them safely, by using the same operator, like below:

- `Task?.Name`
- `Task?.Project?.ServiceOrder?.Customer?.Name`

Based on the above you can follow the way you have already followed for `AccountName` property, but you have also at the same time to use the null conditional operator.

Comment: If I change to the second way, I got the error
An expression tree lambda may not contain a null propagating operator.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need `&&` operator:

```
.Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter?.AccountName) 
    && x?.Account?.Name.ToString().Contains(filter.AccountName))
```

because when you use `||` operator, then you can get `NullReferenceException` in the second part of your expression in `Where`:

```
x?.Account?.Name.ToString().Contains(filter.AccountName))
```

Comment: But in this way, I won't get the right SQL expression